# how to pass a variable that include a string with line break to git message

Tags: string, bash, git, shell, quotes

I have

```
A=123
B="abc${A}efg\n\
ijk"
```

if I `echo $B` it returns:

```
abc123efg
ijk
```

I want to pass B as the git commit message like this:

```
git commit -m $B
```

However, it does not create multiple lines and does not treat `\n` as a line break.

what should I do?

---

update:

this worked

```
git commit -m "$(echo -e "$B")"
```

Comment: Could you clarify what happened when you tried the solution in that question?

Comment: it is not a multiple lines commit message. it is one line with \n in between

Comment: Can you show us _exactly_ what you tried? None of the commands in this question use bash's syntax for expanding escape sequences as described in the linked answer.

Comment: this one worked `git commit -m "$(echo -e "$B")"`

Comment: `echo -e` is buggy by nature -- see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo. Much more reliable to use `git commit -m "$(printf '%b\n' "$B")"`

Comment: That said, you only need `echo -e` or `printf '%b'` if what you have is _not_ a literal linebreak but a two-character `\n` sequence; for a literal linebreak, just `"$B"` (**with the quotes**) works fine (you _absolutely can't_ use `$B` unquoted unless your shell is something like zsh or you've modified IFS, and in the modified-IFS case there are subtle bugs).

Comment: To make things more efficient (avoiding the performance hit of `$()`), you can also use `printf -v B_unescaped '%b\n' "$B"; git commit -m "$B_unescaped"`, at the cost of making your code require extensions that aren't in baseline POSIX sh.